# X509 certificate get PublicKey

Tags: java, security, base64, certificate

I have a X509 Certificate (RSA) string value (start with MII...) encoded in Base64.

I decode it with Base64 and create a X509 Certificate.

```
  public X509Certificate getCertificateX509(CertificateFactory factory, InputStream input) throws XX {
    try {
      return (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(input);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
      throw new XX("");
    }
  }

  public CertificateFactory getCertificateFactoryX509() throws XX {
    try {
      return CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
      throw new XX("");
    }
  }
```

Something I didn't understand is that when I do `x509.getPublicKey().getEncoded()` I get a array of bytes.

Encoded to Base64 I get a new string start with MII (different from the first), I assume isn't the PublicKey ? Only certificate start with MII isn't it ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code part for the two outputs that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate I get is :
`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`

And the x509.PublicKey.getEncoded() in Base64 :
`MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwT3CPpum29ZRqyPq2Rpl4/GpRfE9njN1kje6iOUEIvxoWQ5qB/H8VFFkph7U9mb/QK+7Rt/9d/dCTdru2BfMPskbXYGphetQDY3e8DEQCoRXNnYy2dzkkj1uJWuLFEwZwEH7ZHpEP9HnWWoEBEu0r6jCJBniJRrzU8UHKZ5S5fkG/BOcvAJIdCyS1HeCrOaQ47POixi7bd0P0+sfXIjSlY6ef8W8C3kR3o+mVMZozkC8PApoQzbCWMsFp1QGlLuSkeP+FXNuRHm1r6NX1UVDsS7+S+x8dXc48VqVxwTG5GAlwShQ69pTBqRsY0EPNeVYcmpdZ0/d4tufd5yIiVRvsQIDAQAB`

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.

String"MII" is begin of base64 string format.

if you need to byte of public key Only use of this code:

```
byte[] public = x509.getPublicKey();
```

and get string of public key:

```
byte[] public = x509.getPublicKeyString();
```

this function return public key as byte for you.

but using of .getEncoded() function return base64 of bytes of public key.

Comment: As of OpenJDK17, `X509Certificate` does not have `#getPublicKeyString` method.